# Shiny module updateTextInput or more generally all update*Inputs don't work despite the session

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

In the same Shiny App, I have two modules, which have a similar architecture with an `observeEvent`. Both `observeEvent`s update the input fields. In one of the modules this action works just fine. In the other one it does not work for some reason.

- Both modules have the `ns("id")` for the inputs.
- `update*Inputs` have the session information
- `observeEvent`s are triggered in both cases
- There are no errors on the server or browser side, which indicates anything.
- There are some submodules. If there are some actions in the subsubmodule, then the module update*Input works once.

I think this must be a weird bug but is there any way to even investigate it?

```
module_ui = function(id){
  ns = NS(id)
  ...
  textInput(ns("textid"), ...)
  ...
}
module_server = function(id){
  moduleServer(id,
    function(input, output, session){
      ...
      observeEvent(reac(), {
        print("trigger indicator")
        updateTextInput(session, "textid", value = reac())
      }
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, there was an error, which I saw in Firefox but not in RStudio's browser. One of the sub-submodules did not manage to set an input value, which was an empty vector. This blocked the rest of the javascript action. Therefore, no values were displayed.

Lesson: if update*Input does not work, this can be due to unnoticed errors in other modules.

Answer (score 0):

Given the situation you are describing, i would try printing rec(), i am assuming this is a reactive value, in the observeEvent() to see what its value the updateTextInput is executing.

I suspect there is something up it when it is passed into the observeEvent causing it to set to the same value.

Comment: if you mean the reac(), yes, it is the value I expect, which is not displayed in the textInput.